# Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException'

Tags: android-studio, jenkins, gradle, centos, android-instrumentation

I get this error when I build Android Studio project from Jenkins.

```
Starting 6 tests on test10_googleAPIs(AVD) - 4.1.2

com.MobileTornado.sdk.newclient.screens.login.MessageScreenTest > AAA_signIn[test10_googleAPIs(AVD) - 4.1.2] [31mFAILED [0m
Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException''. Check device logcat for details
Tests on test10_googleAPIs(AVD) - 4.1.2 failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException'
:new-client:connectedDevDebugAndroidTest FAILED
```

The code is compiled, then starts running the tests from the project and then falls.

I use here gradle, junit, espresso and emulator.

In addition, when I build the project on Windows machine, it's successful. But with the Linux machine(centOS) failed.

I searched for an answer all over the net. Some offer to change the code. But it's a very big project and the code run on windows machine.

Any suggestion?

Comment: did you solve this?